# Returning a value based on date of return

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula

Please I need help.

I have a column called "Date_Of_Return". I want to create a calculated field to return "SMP" if the arrival date is greater than "01-11-2021" and return "JI" if otherwise.

I came up with this but it's not working effectively.

Any help will do please.

```
SMP = IF('NEW EUTF UPDATED PORTAL II'[Date_Of_Return] >= DATEVALUE("01-11-2021"),"SMP","JI"())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using below formula for your calculated column:

```
=IF([Date_Of_Return] > DATE(2021,11,1), "SMP", "JI")
```

Where `DATE(2021,11,1)` is in format: `DATE(yyyy,mm,dd)`

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).